# Multiple SpringBootTests using EmbeddedKafka fails with "only one 'RetryTopicConfigurationSupport'"

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-boot-test, embedded-kafka

We have an application that makes use of Spring Kafka's non blocking retries via the `RetryableTopic` annotation.

We are in the middle of upgrading spring-kafka from 2.8.4 to 2.9.0.

We have several `SpringBootTest`s that makes use of `EmbeddedKafka`.  Each of these tests are marked with `DirtyContext` and `AutoConfigureMockMvc`

After upgrading, the first test would run fine, but the later test would fail to start the application with

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one 'RetryTopicConfigurationSupport' is allowed
```

I understand that the `RetryTopicConfigurationSupport` tries to ensures only one instance of itself is ever instantiated.  So in the use case of running multiple unit tests, which includes multiple different `SpringBootTest`s, how do we avoid hitting this problem?

I have tried marking the context dirty, but of course that didn't solve the problem as RetryTopicConfigurationSupport is using a static variable to track whether it has been instantiated before or not.

I have tried NOT marking the ContextDirty, but the later tests would fail to start the application because the Port is already in use.

Appreciate any advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this problem has been addressed in spring-kafka 3.0 and backported to 2.9.3
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2477